# Export bootstrap material dashboard page

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-4, export, material-design

I have free bootstrap material dashboard from https://github.com/creativetimofficial/material-dashboard
I want to add export button to export all dashboard page with images , widgets , material-icons and material-cars and everything in page like we capture all pages with print screen button .

Answer (score 0):

I will give advice that will make your path easier
Use the admin area for inspiration to create your own.
Only the appearance, write everything else yourself, if you are not familiar with the Material, then you should not install at all